# django form 2 drop downs, manytomany?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a form and attempting to pre populate it dynamically.

Example: if a user selected ('Front End', 'Front End'), we would return css, html, javascript to them where they could select the relevant languages (via a check box, multi choice)required for the role.

I don't think I have enough models created. Also I think this will take 2 forms, one to create all of this data, and another to return it to display it for users to use.

```
#models.py 

TITLE_CHOICES = (('Select', 'Select'),
    ('Front End', 'Front End'),
    ('Back End', 'Back End'),
    ('Mobile', 'Mobile'),
    ('Other', 'Other')
    )


class Role(models.Model):
    profiletitle = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=TITLE_CHOICES, default='Select')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.profiletitle
```

My problem is in my form. I need a second drop down that is related to profile "Languages".  I'm not sure how to use manytomanyfield to relate profiletitle selection to languages.

The languages drop down/check boxes should display only the related languages to the selected profiletitle selected.

Thanks for reading/helping.

PS. I am trying to do this with Django, no JavaScript, and I am working on App Engine. (no joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in Django without any JS you will have to let the form submit. And load a second form.

I'm not sure if you're using Class Based Views or functional views but regardless, your logic should be:

1. Form 1: Have user select role (i.e. front end, back end, etc, ..) and press submit (post the form)
2. When you process this form in your django view, take the selected choice (front end, back end, etc) and do a query for the relevant languages and use that queryset/choices as the choices for the languages form input and redirect the view to this form (Form 2).

I don't know why you don't want javascript but you can look at [this link](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) (and many others out there) on dynamic forms

Note: Since I don't see any code I can only suggest you take this direction, guessing you'd do it the way I would given you restraints..